# What's the first language that had the 'Unless' conditional/loop built into itself?

Tags: programming-languages, history

What's the first *(oldest)* language that had the 'Unless' conditional/loop built into itself?

Where an example could be

```
unless (myVar) == if (!myVar)

until (myVar) == while (!myVar)
```

Comment: Is this just in Perl & Ruby? It's not one I've come across before.

Comment: I found it in Common Lisp yesterday, and I just had a discussion with a friend that lead to this question. Not sure whether it existed in MACLISP..

Comment: That's an odd interpretation of "unless". I would have defined it as `unless (myVar) == if (!myVar)` and `until (myVar) == while (!myVar)`.

Comment: @Adam Paynter: That's what `unless` and `until` do in Ruby and Perl. I'm not quite sure which language the OP is talking about.

Comment: The above example was one interpretation that I had come across - apparently there are varieties!

Comment: Pascal had a `repeat`...`until` loop, but not `unless`.

Comment: Out of interest... why do you want to know this?

Comment: @Steve Haigh: Mainly out of curiosity - we were both unaccustomed to it. It immediately broke the flow of logic when either of us came across it, so we discussed it and arrived to this question in the end.

Comment: Yep, it's not something I've seen before.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

actually I've found a copy of the 1967 BCPL language manual with the UNLESS statement in it on section 6.7

http://www.fh-jena.de/~kleine/history/languages/Richards-BCPL-ReferenceManual.pdf

this was also the first language to demonstrate the "Hello World" program

BCPL became "B" at Bell Labs and then later "C"

the joke was that the real question was what would the next language be "P" from the BCPL or "D" from the Alphabetic order

Comment: Great first answer, hope you stick around and write more quality content like this here.

Answer (score 3):

The first language I ever saw with an UNLESS statement was [Intercal](http://www.catb.org/~esr/intercal/), whose primary control structure was the `COME FROM ... UNLESS ...` statement.  Intercal wasn't designed as a serious language, but it does date from 1972, and you can program in it (why you'd want to is another matter).

Answer (score 2):

I think it originated with [BASIC-PLUS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BASIC-PLUS) on Digital systems in the '70s.

The Perl documentation mentions this heritage (run `perldoc perl` and look in the DESCRIPTION)

Answer (score -1):

LISP, invented in 1958, though not sure when LISP got the UNLESS keyword.